# Smaller back button and thinner address bar in Firefox 30

Tags: firefox, user-interface

I'm using the latest stable Firefox 30.0. I'm bothered by the big round Back button and the wide address bar that goes with it.

[image: Firefox Big Back Button Example]

I would like it to change it to a lean Back button (just a rectangle) and a thin address bar.

The usual advice is to right-click the toolbar, click *Customize* and enable "Use small icons". But Firefox redesigned the browser customization recently and the new look doesn't have this option.

I'm open to installing add-ons to solve this, but a browser-only solution gets priority.

*Note: I'm not looking for rectangular tabs.*

> **Clarification:**
>   My main intention in asking this was to **reclaim the wasted space** from the wide address bar. I like the Australis look, and I don't mind having it (with the round Back button). For this reason, I picked *Australis Small Icons* over the *Classic Theme Restorer*.

Comment: If you load the Stylish add-on (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/?src=external-userstyleshome), it gives you a front end to a vast searchable collection of themes and modifications for almost every aspect of the user interface.  You can also try them out before you install them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I don't know of any browser-only solution. I guess there's none like that.

So, I will advise you to install an add-on like the [Classic Theme Restorer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/classicthemerestorer/) or [Australis Small Icons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/australis-small-icons/). You will get the small icons and the thin bar.

If you want to get back the rectangle tab (not Australis, like before), choose the *Classic Theme Restorer* add-on.

Comment: Neither add-ons seem to change the **round Back button** to a rectangular one that takes up less space. I don't want rectangular tabs. Thanks though. PS: Don't use code blocks for non-code content. Please use italics, quote marks, etc.

Comment: *FWIW,* I tried the **Australis Small Icons** add-on and I'm happy that the tab bar and address bar are now taking up **24%** less space. The *Back* button is still round, but it's not so bad. Thanks! `:)`

Comment: 24% exactly... like you measured it in pixels??? o_O

Comment: Well, not *exactly*. How does **23.94366197183099%** sound to you? `:D` Yes, measured in pixels. *Original: 71 pixels wide. After enabling add-on: 54 pixels wide.*

Comment: To expand on my previous comment: Classic Theme Restorer has an option called "Movable back-forward button". When activated, it restores the square-ish buttons.

Comment: Thanks @Doktoro for pointing it out. But I'm growing to like the look of Australis with *Australis Small Icons*. Although I mentioned I want a squarish Back button, my main intention was to reclaim the wasted space. The add-on I picked does this very well, and therefore I don't mind the Back button still being round (but I'm glad it's smaller).

Comment: I'm glad to heard that :) and thanks for the advice and fix. At the moment, I didn't know how formatting my message. I'm not very familiar with that...  Also for the button, I wasn't totally sure to understand that you will. Anyway, if you really wanted it back, I think you should looking for something like the [Classic Toolbar Buttons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cstbb/) add-on.

Answer (score 2):

1. Install [Classic Toolbar Buttons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cstbb/).
2. Enable small buttons in addon settings.

Comment: A little more detail to Greg's solution. It is Preference --> General UI --> Mode --> Show icons only. Thanks Greg!